# Dropped event because it is stale caused by minifyEnabled set to true

Tags: android, android-proguard

I made some small changes to my android app (moved a library locally, upgraded gradle plugin to last, ...) and now if I use "minifyEnabled true", my app freezes at start:

> I/WindowManager: Input event dispatching timed out sending to
>   net.myapp/net.myapp.view.mView.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event
>   because the touched window has not finished processing certain input
>   events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length:
>   5.  Wait queue head age: 5520.8ms.

And if I touch the screen, I get:

> I/InputDispatcher: Dropped event because it is stale.

Besides that, I cannot see anything in the logs.
Setting minifyEnabled to false works. How can I find the exact source of the problem?

Comment: Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774771/inputdispatcher-dropped-event-because-input-dispatch-is-disabled

Comment: This does not seem related.

Answer (score 0):

So, trying to understand the reason of my problem, I removed proguard. Then I had the methods limit of dex (random errors saying it could not find methods and classes of my app) and moved to multidex and everything solved.

So I'm not sure this was the problem, but if it may help someone you can refer to this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle